# ClassNotFoundException for some spring dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have a maven web application that has some spring dependencies, but I am getting a classnotfoundexception for `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`so for some reason, the jar isn't getting included in the lib directory.

Here is my maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>temp</groupId>
    <artifactId>TemperatureWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>TemperatureWebApp</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <war.outputName>TemperatureApp</war.outputName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFileNameMapping>${war.outputName}</outputFileNameMapping>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<scope>compile</scope>` from dependencies. Due to this, the [jars are not getting bundled](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dependency+Scopes) in the resulting 'war' archive.

Comment: My understanding from what I have read is that compile is the default scope if none is provided, and it wasn't working without it, so I figured I would try it anyway. 'Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.'

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at naming my war file was the problem:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${war.outputName}</outputFileNameMapping>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I removed the `outputFileNameMapping` declaration, and now the jars are included in the WAR.

Comment: wondering how is `outputFileNameMapping` is related to jar inclusions. I tried searching something but without success.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I noticed that when I had it included, the lib directory did have a file named TemperatureWebApp, just a file, no associated type, which was strange, so that was when I had the idea to just remove that, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "Maven Dependency" in the Deployement Assembly

--    right click on your project and choose properties.

--    click on Deployement Assembly.

--    click add

--    click on "Java Build Path Entries"

--    select Maven Dependencies"

--   click Finish.

hope it may work for you.